# Can nginx be used to front sharded, HTTP-based resources?

Tags: nginx, couchdb, sharding

**Info**

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is a RESTful, HTTP-based NoSQL datastore. Responses are sent back in simple JSON and it is capable of [utilizing ETags](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#ETags.2BAC8-Caching) in the generated responses to help caching servers tell if data has changed or not.

**Question**

Is it possible to use nginx to front a collection of CouchDB servers where each Couch server is a shard of a larger collection (and not replicas of each other) and have it determine the target shard based on a particular aspect of the query string?

Example Queries:

```
http://db.mysite.com?id=1
http://db.mysite.com?id=2
```

Shard Logic:

```
shard = ${id} % 2; // even/odd
```

This isn't a straight forward "load balancing" question because I would need the same requests to always end up at the same servers, but I am curious if this type of simple routing logic can be written into an nginx site configuration.

If it can be, what makes this solution so attractive is that you can then turn on [nginx caching of the JSON responses](http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2011/07/nginx-json-hacks.html) from the Couch servers and have the entire setup nicely packaged up and deployed in a very capable and scalable manner.

Answer (score 1):

You could cobble something together or you could use BigCouch (https://github.com/cloudant/bigcouch).

Comment: Robert, 2 questions. (1) In the readme it mentions a magic number, do BigCouch nodes auth with each other using this magic value? (2) In the docs under "Now what" the 2nd paragraph suggests a load-balance because "All nodes can handle requests equally", so are these all master-master-* replicas of each other, or shards? If shards, do these nodes pass-through queries to the correct targets when a request comes in on the WRONG node? Why do the docs encourage a load balancer directly to the nodes and circumventing the hashing BigCouch front on port 5984?

Comment: 1) I think you mean the erlang cookie? If so, yes. 2) it's both replicated (multiple copies of any document) and sharded (multiple, disjoint subsets of your data held in different databases). You can query any document at any node and bigcouch will perform the correct internal lookup. Therefore you can round-robin over all nodes freely. Round-robin to the front port. If you hit the back port, you'll have to reimplement all the hashing/sharding/clustering work, it would be pointless.

Comment: Ahhh ok, the front-port on each of the nodes, I was thinking there was one-front port. Thank you for the clarification. As for the replicates + shards, if I am sharding because my data set has outgrown the capacity of a single Couch server (say I have a 1TB collection I want in 5 200GB shards), can I tell BC to just shard and not duplicate so I end up with 5TB + shards.size()?

Comment: yes, you can pass ?n=1 when you create the database, then you only have 1 copy of each doc. pass ?q=5 to make 5 shards (8 is the default).